# floating jquery menu UI above it's containing div

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I have a div (it's a popup for an openlayers map, but it could pretty much be any fixed size div), that contains a jquery ui menu (which is wrapped in a ul). The menu doesn't fit inside the div very well, so I'd like to make the menu float above it so that as the menu grows I don't have to grow the size of the containing div. Is this possible?

The containing div is itself positioned absolutely, I've tried setting the `ul` that represents the menu to `position:absolute;z-index:100` but that doesn't work. I've also tried setting `overflow:visible` with no joy.

This screenshot shows the issue I have:

[image: Screen grab]

I've added a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattwoberts/MBEBD/5/) that opens a popup when you click the small orange circle, and you can see that the menu inside there is bigger than the containing div.

Comment: can you give us your code or jsFiddle

Comment: append your `ul` to `div.olMapViewport`, give `position: absolute` calculate left and top values based on `button#popup_actions` position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tell me that my answer is not what you mean I will delete it cause I am not sure what you really need to do. You want this scrolls to disappear and if the text is bigger than the popup just to float over no matter it is going outline ?

If this is what you want you have to remove the `overflow: auto` from `.olFramedCloudPopupContent` and again to remove `overflow: auto` from inline style of the element `#chicken_contentDiv` (I am not sure that you add it with jQuery).

Comment: Thanks - that removes the scroll bars, but doesn't help the menu float above. Also, there is no `overflow:auto` in the inline style on the #chicken_ContentDiv (did you mean somewhere else?)

Comment: It might be some plugin you use, but it set `overflow: auto` on `#chicken_contentDiv`. You can try inspecting it with firebug go to that element and you will see :)

Comment: Yup, inspecting with firebug or chrome dev tools doesn't show that for me - just on the .olFramedCloudPopupContent. Once I've removed that though, surely I need to set something on the `ul` to make it float?

Comment: I'm going to give you the points - you were right I needed to turn off overflow:auto but I also needed to set overflow:visible on this element and the parent divs